# IP Redirection with iptables and vsphere

Tags: linux, iptables, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, linux-networking

I use **ESX4.1** (vmware vsphere4) and I have one Public IP (X.X.X.X) in **vswif0** and (192.168.1.1) in **vswif1** and 2 virtual machines with local IP (192.168.1.2) and (192.168.1.3)

I want to use iptables firewall to redirect all iconming traffic to x.x.x.x:**80** to 192.168.1.2:**8080** and x.x.x.x:**3306** to 192.168.1.3:**3308**

Could any body help me!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need the following iptables commands:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -d x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:8080
iptables -A PREROUTING -d x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:3308
```

You need to make sure IP forwarding is enabled and the traffic is allowed in filter table.